# Firebase Anonymous Login - Why FirebaseID changes when logged to Facebook, but it remains the same when not logged to Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following logic for allowing guest users to login to my app:

```
    (1) Login as Anonymous. 
    (2) Check if Facebook is logged. 
    (3)    If it is logged to Facebook, link to Anonymous. 
    (4)        If link fails, Login to firebase passing facebook token to Firebase
```

If I am not logged in Facebook the Anonymous ID given by firebase after step (1) is always the same. However, the first time I login to Facebook, I link the account to firebase as in step (3). And from that onwards, I get a different Anonymous ID every time I go through the login process.

**Question 1.** Will the Anonymous ID in step (1) ALWAYS be the same until I login to Facebook for the first time?

**Question 2.** What is the best login flow to allow users to save data in the backend as guests, and link to facebook later when the user decides to do so?

Here is my swift code that implements my pseudo code:

```swift
func login() -> Promise<AuthCredential?> {
        // Login as Anonymous. Check if FB is logged. If it is, link to Anonymous. If fails, pass FB token to Firebase
        print("........................")
        print("Starting Login")
        return Promise { seal in
            Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
                print("-Done Login Anonymously", authResult?.credential, Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
            if let error = error {
                print("-DID NOT SIGNED UP WITH FIREBASE:", error)
                seal.reject(error)
            } else {
                if AccessToken.isCurrentAccessTokenActive { // If Facebook token is active exchange for Firebase

                    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
                    print("-Loggged with FACEBOOK!!!!", credential)
                    Auth.auth().currentUser!.link(with: credential) { (result, error) in
                        print("-Linked Account!!!!??????????", result as Any, error as Any)
                        if error != nil {
                            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                            print("-Signed UP in Firebase USIG FB. No Linking")
                            if let error = error {
                                print("-DID NOT SIGNED UP WITH FIREBASE:", error)
                                seal.reject(error)
                            } else {
                                print("-DID SIGNED UP WITH FIREBASE using FB:", Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

                                seal.fulfill(authResult?.credential)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
//                print("-Done Login", Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
//                seal.fulfill(authResult?.credential)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation for [signInAnonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inanonymously) (javascript) reads:

> If there is already an anonymous user signed in, that user will be
>   returned; otherwise, a new anonymous user identity will be created and
>   returned.

You probably only want to call signInAnonymously if there is no user signed into the app.  It's best to wait to see if a user is already signed in using an auth state listener, as the sign-in process is not immediate.

Once you link the anonymous account with a full account, you should probably not call signInAnonymously again, since you probably want the user to stay signed in with their full account and no create another new anon account.

Comment: If I close and then open gain my app, will be my mobile be logged in?

Comment: The user sign in state of a web app has no effect on the sign in state of a mobile app.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear. Another way to ask what I wanted to ask in my previous comment is if my Anonymous token expires.

Comment: Anonymous logins don't automatically expire.  If the user uninstalls the app, the anonymous account is still registered with Firebase, but the user can no longer user it, because the token was deleted with the uninstall.